# Adding custom sprite object to a view

Tags: ios, swift, class, sprite, nsobject

I'm making a game and built a custom NSObject sprite class for it. What I want to do is when my view loads add a visual representation of my object. I don't think it should be that hard but this is my first time trying to get a custom class to render on the screen. Also I want to do this without using Sprite Kit. Here is a stripped down version of what my sprite class looks like.

```
class sprite: NSObject {
    var img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "koalio_stand")!

    var width = 10
    var height = 10

    var x, y: Int!
    var velocity: Int!
}
```

Comment: Views should extend `UIView`, not `NSObject`.

Comment: Wow thanks that fixed everything.